# Two XCode installed, co-work strange crash 100%.

Tags: xcode, crash

Install two XCode v4.3 and v4.5, find one strange issue if the project file opened by v4.5 at first, close then open by v4.3, then it will crash 100%. How to resolve it? Anyone who knows please share. Thanks.

And another question is how to set v4.3 by default? Click project file it will invoke v4.3 automatically, instead of current v4.5.

Comment: Are you using `xcode-select` to switch between tools used by Xcode?

Comment: Yes, but it still works bad as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by remove produced library files in ~/Library/....